# Phaser adding arcade physics messes up sprites

Tags: phaser-framework

When I add Arcade physics to my sprites the whole game breaks and the sprites behave very oddly.

When the two lines to enable physics are commented out I get the behaviour I was expecting.

```
//game.physics.arcade.enable(paddle);
//game.physics.arcade.enable(ball);
```

I am trying to add it in so I can do some collision detection.

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

function preload() {

    game.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
    game.load.image('paddle', 'assets/reactangle.jpg');
    game.load.image('circle', 'assets/circle.png');

}

var paddle; 
var ball; 
var ballDir;
var ballSpeed;

function create() {
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'sky');

    paddle = game.add.sprite(game.width/2  ,500, 'paddle');

    ballSpeed = 5
    ballDir = -ballSpeed;

    ball = game.add.sprite(10, 10, 'circle');

    ball.x = 400;
    ball.y = 20;
    game.physics.arcade.enable(paddle);
    game.physics.arcade.enable(ball);
}

function update() {
    paddle.x = game.input.mousePointer.x - (paddle.width/2);
    ball.y -= ballDir;
}
```

Comment: You didn't close your `create` function; I assume that was just an issue with pasting your code in? And then can you clarify what you're running into? Once the `create` function is properly closed I'm not experiencing any issues.

Comment: @JamesSkemp not closing my create function was a pasting error. When I run the code, the rectangle image is continually moved between the mouse pos and a different x position rapidly.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally set the `paddle` speed? I mean something like `paddle.body.speed = -20`.

Comment: I can't replicate that with the code you provided above. https://jsfiddle.net/strivinglife/mcop5ag2/